# How to start SMTP virtualhost [SMTP Virtual Server #1] through powershell or command prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, smtp, virtualhost, windows-command-prompt

Because of some error on my server, my `SMTP` service `[SMTP Virtual Server #1]` stops. I want to create job which will run periodically to check the `SMTP` server status, if it is stopped then the script will start it again.

I have used `Start-Service "SMTPSVC"` but it only starts the `UATSERV` service and not the `[SMTP Virtual Server #1]` virtual host (please have a look of the attached image).

How do I start the virtual server after the service is started?

My admin team is working on the issue. I wanted to use this temporary solution in the mean time.

Any help is appreciated... :)

[image: SMTP virtual host image]

Comment: This doesn't actually work, at least in Windows 2008. It puts a Red X over the SMTP server but telnet tests to port 25 show that its not really working, at least not for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**To Start:**

```
$SMTP=[adsi]"IIS://localhost/SMTPSVC/1"
$SMTP.ServerState = 2
$SMTP.SetInfo()
```

**To Stop:**

```
$SMTP=[adsi]"IIS://localhost/SMTPSVC/1"
$SMTP.ServerState = 4
$SMTP.SetInfo()
```

Comment: By Mistake you are entered wrong ServerState for START & STOP the SMTP.

Comment: ServerState 2 For START & ServerState 4 for STOP. Thanks Again....

Comment: fyi, this doesn't stop/start the server on windows 2012, it only changes the icon this worked for me: `$SMTP=[adsi]"IIS://localhost/SMTPSVC/1"`  `$SMTP.Stop() or .Start()`

Comment: This did not work for me on Windows Server 2008R2. As above, the status appears to change in IIS Manager, but the actual status of the service is not affected.

Comment: As a heads-up, I found that the object does not "update" in PowerShell if the state is changed. For example, if `$SMTP.ServerState` is 2, then you use `$SMTP.Stop()` or stop it externally, then `$SMTP.ServerState` will STILL BE 2. You have to re-initialize `$SMTP` again to get the accurate state again.

Answer (score 1):

Actual working answer is here:

```
([ADSI]'IIS://LOCALHOST/SMTPSVC/1').Start()
([ADSI]'IIS://LOCALHOST/SMTPSVC/1').Stop()
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37432396/3321505